# Show $\neg (W \to W), (W \leftrightarrow W) \wedge W, E \vee (W \to \neg (E \wedge W))$ are jointly inconsistent.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 182, exercise B. 9):

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\neg (W \to W)\\(W \leftrightarrow W) \wedge W\\E \vee (W \to \neg (E \wedge W))}{
 \fitch{W}{
    W
 }\\
 W \to W\\
 \bot
}
$

As I understand, I need to derive a contradiction assuming those sentences as premises. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Correct........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is sufficient.

You can also argue that the first premise is *by itself* a contradiction (because it cannot be satisfied by *any* interpretation of $W$), so therefore *all three premises* do form a *jointly inconsistent set* (since there is no interpretation of $\{E,W\}$ that will simultaneously satisfy *all* of them).